# How to save multidimensional pseudoArray to localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array:

```
state = [
[ "depth":0,
  "id":1,
  "desc":"something",
  "prof": [ 
    ["ID":1, "ID_ZASOB":1],
    ["ID":5, "ID_ZASOB":4] 
    ] 
],
[ "depth":2,
  "id":3,
  "desc":"somethingOther",
  "prof": [ 
    ["ID":2, "ID_ZASOB":5],
    ["ID":2, "ID_ZASOB":1]
    ] 
],
]
```

And I have to store it in localstorage.

I tried json.stringify, but this is not an object, it's an array,

Comment: _"but this is not an object, it's an array"_ No, it's a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

This is an incorrect way of writing arrays.You are mixing arrays with objects
An array cannot have keys

```
state = [
{ "depth":0,
  "id":1,
  "desc":"something",
  "prof": [ 
    {"ID":1, "ID_ZASOB":1},
    {"ID":5, "ID_ZASOB":4}
    ] 
},
{ "depth":2,
  "id":3,
  "desc":"somethingOther",
  "prof": [ 
    {"ID":2, "ID_ZASOB":5},
    {"ID":2, "ID_ZASOB":1}
    ] 
}
]
```

Now you can stringify it